# Cloud SQL : can a read replica serve for HA

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm confused about the ability of read replicates to serve HA, from this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication#read-replicas)
we have :

> As a best practice, put read replicas in a different zone than the primary instance when you use HA on your primary instance. This practice ensures that **read replicas continue to operate when the zone that contains the primary instance has an outage**.

which means that it can be used for HA, and it can replace primary node in case of zonal failure.

Howerver, from this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/high-availability#read_replicas) it says :

> Read replicas cannot be made highly available like primary instances. **During a zonal outage, traffic to read replicas in that zone stops.**

which means that it can't be HA, and can't replace primary instance in case of zonal failure

Did I miss some thing ?

Answer (score 0):

[Read replicas](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication#rr-info) do not provide High Availability as it cannot be promoted to become the primary database instance when needed. Read replicas are read-only; you cannot write to them. So, you need to configure HA (for write operations).

However, the reason for putting the read replicas in a different zone than the primary instance serves a different purpose. If the read replicas are in the same zone as the primary instance, then both the instances are lost in the case of zonal failure. So for HA with Read replicas, one more Read replica will be required in a different zone. Please refer to this [diagram](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/high-availability#normal) to understand the optimal recommended configuration for this scenario.